# How to restore all nuget packages in a solution?

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have a solution with 12 projects. The idea is to avoid all dependencies issues and whoever downloads the latest solution from TFS would just run one command at the solution level which would install all the packages in all the 12 projects.

I have the packages.config file in individual projects and I run the following command to install it at project level

nuget install pathtoproject\packages.config

this works and it installs all the required references from packges.config. But I will have to execute this command 12 times for 12 projects. Is there one command at the solution level  which would install all packages.config?

I tried
 nuget.exe restore solutionname

and nothing happened. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: If you right-click the solution, select "manage nuget packages for solution" when the nuget window comes up, it should have a bar at the top asking you to restore all packages.  Is that not working, or acceptable?

Comment: You are right. the requirement is to get a  command line specific solution.

Comment: *"I tried nuget.exe restore solutionname and nothing happened."* I doubt that. What did Nuget say in the console when you ran this?

Comment: when i execute nuget.exe restore command I get a "All packages listed in packages.config' are already installed.

Comment: So how would I force nuget to look in the project's packages.config file and not the solution's packages.config file

Comment: @Will That method is **deprecated** as of NuGet 2.7 and TFS 2013. https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

Comment: @DanielMann link or it didn't depreciate. Ed.  Or something.  If you know this, then perhaps you know the replacement?  And, OP, maybe it didn't "do anything" because your packages were already installed?  Delete your /packages folder and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio 2013 update 3 or more you just build your solution. The result of NuGet packages is automation on both the client and the build server.

Comment: But to make sure that all developers use the same version of an assembly we are not going to auto download the reference. We are hoping that a command line install would install all the references with correct versions

Comment: There is no automatic version update. You need to manually increment the version and check in. So all developed will always get the same version.

Answer (score 0):

too late to reply, in case someone lands here..

"All packages listed in packages.config' are already installed"

if you see this message then i think the packages are actually restored, probably visual studio not showing it in the solution explorer view. A simple refresh did the trick for us.